# Formate Date From String?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I Have NSString * DateString  With Value    "01-10-2013 09:43:45"

And I Wanna Formate Date From It and My Code Is

```
 NSDateFormatter * DateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
            DateFormatter.dateFormat=@"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss";
            NSDate * Date =[DateFormatter dateFromString:DateString];
```

But when i Log The Date It's Value is 2013-01-10 07:43:45 +0000 
Any help please

Comment: What is your test device's time zone set to?

Comment: Sorry Cannot understand .

Comment: Is the input string local time or UTC?

Comment: input string is local time

Comment: BTW, it's poor form to have variable names with leading caps.  Use "dateFormatter" and "date", not "DateFormatter" and "Date".

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the `NSDateFormatter` to the correct time zone.

If the input string is in "local time" then use this:

```
NSDateFormatter *DateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[DateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];   // <--- Set to local time
DateFormatter.dateFormat=@"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss";
NSDate * Date =[DateFormatter dateFromString:DateString];
```

If the input string is in UTC/GMT, then use this instead:

```
NSDateFormatter *DateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[DateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];   // <--- Set to UTC
DateFormatter.dateFormat=@"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss";
NSDate * Date =[DateFormatter dateFromString:DateString];
```

Comment: Dear trojanfoe . The Result is still "2013-01-10 07:43:45 +0000"

Comment: @Tefa - If the value didn't change when you changed the timezone then you did something wrong.

Comment: @Tefa how are you getting that string?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set locale

```
...
[DateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
...
```

But if you want cut "+0000" string you can use

```
[s substringToIndex:s.length - 5];
```

Comment: There's no need to "cut" the timezone offset out of the description/NSLog output -- one should NEVER use that format for user interfaces, so there's no need to remove it.